# Where is iOS subtitle setting for Enterprise applications in XCode

Tags: ios, enterprise, subtitle

My enterprise applications (not in public app store) are starting to look like this when looking at Settings -> General -> iPhone Storage where the subtitle is showing "LaunchMeSubtitle".  Where is this setting in XCode?

Note: This is not the Organization field, as I do have it populated, and it's not showing here.

[image: photo of app info]

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the developer name, which is not an Xcode setting. According to the docs, it looks like you'll need to set it correctly the first time: https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev32bdcc4b6

Check your app store connect home page to see if the dev/company name there matches what's shown here. I believe you can contact apple and see if they can switch it.

Comment: This is an enterprise application distributed by our internal MDM solution.  It's not in the public iTunesConnect App Store

Comment: I would double check with your internal solution if there is a setting for developer name